# Реализация UnitOfWork ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, repository, core

Хочу реализовать в проекте UnitOfWork. При рассмотрении примеров, возник вопрос. Как правильно получить репозиторий? В некоторых примерах репозиторий создают: `return _Repository = _Repository ?? new Repository(_databaseContext)` , а в некоторых передают через конструктор (DI). То же самое и контекст данных, создавать новый или инжектить? Как делать правильно?

Comment: Однозначно "правильно" не бывает. Но агрегация (внедрение зависимостей через конструктор) предпочтительнее в подавляющем большинстве случаев, чем композиция (создание зависимостей внутри). См. http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/12/vs-vs.html

Comment: Попробуйте покрыть код модульными тестами. Удаётся замокать все зависимости?

Comment: Посмотрите как устроен Entity Framework: в нём есть и репозитории и UoW из коробки. Кстати, если у вас в проекте уже используется EF то вы просто делаете свои самопальные репозитории поверх репозиториев и UoW поверх UoW (и не факт, что это стоит делать)